# Adding setter to @State property impossible?

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

If I change `@State var pan: Int` to this:

```swift
  @State var pan: Int {
    set(x) {
      self.pan = min(max((x), -50), 50)
    }
    get {
      return self.pan
    }
  }
```

I get the error: `Cannot apply property wrapper to computed property.` The error goes away when I remove the `@State` wrapper.

But then I get the message, `Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable`

Is there some way that I can get both?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: No, you can't get both.

Why not simply a second (computed) property

```
@State private var pan = 0

var panWrapper: Int {
    get { pan }
    set { pan = min(max((newValue), -50), 50) }
 }
```

Or alternatively a `@Binding`

```
let panBinding = Binding {
    pan
} set: {
    pan = min(max(($0), -50), 50) }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. How would the binding work in the code that currently just accesses the `@State var pan: Int`?  Would I just substitute `panBinding` for `pan` in all spots?

Comment: The context the code is used in is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, something like this:

```
struct Content {
    var pan: Int {
    set {
      _pan = min(max((newValue), -50), 50)
    }
    get {
      return _pan
    }
  }
   var _pan: Int = 0

   //mutating func otherLogic(){}
}


struct ContentView : View {

    @State var content = Content()   

    // use content.pan
...
```

Comment: Since my PanView is just the visual editor for another class's property this might work if I create a 2-way `has-a`...  I suppose everywhere I currently have `pan`, I'd just substitute `content.pan`?

Comment: Change the other class to a struct and pass a binding to the struct into the editor.